# How do I correct this silent failure to write files using Java IO?

Tags: java, io, apache-commons, java-io

I am encountering a strange issue with the commons-io/java-io. Essentially my file creation is failing silently without an exception.

```
FileUtils.writeLines(file, collectionOfStrings);
```

I've looked through the commons code to try and figure why this failing silently, but to me it looks like it should be throwing an exception. (See lines 1338, 163 in [FileUtils.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/io/tags/commons-io-1.4/src/java/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java) and line 927 in [IOUtils.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/io/tags/commons-io-1.4/src/java/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.java).)

In an effort to try to correct this issue, I added this check to the code after the previous line,

```
if (!file.exists()) {
    logger.warn("File creation failed.");
}
```

However, even when file creation fails, this block is not being entered.

I'm at my wits end with this one, can anyone with more experience with Java IO help me out?

Comment: Are you sure the file does not exist? Maybe it's a temporary file created by the application?

Comment: Well to give a little more context to the question, when running locally under my ID, the file is created on a network share I have access to. But when running under Tomcat in a web context, as a local service, the file is never created, which makes sense to me. However I am just trying to log that the file was never created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little embarrassed but I forgot to include the commons-io jar with my web application. Resulting in a run time issue.

My real issue was that the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils
message was not going into my log because **NoClassDefFoundError is NOT an exception**, wonderful architecture by Sun here.

When this NoClassDefFoundError was hit, the rest of the code didn't execute, including the file.exists() check.

Comment: Future note, if you want to catch any failures for your log, catch Throwable, not Exception.

Comment: @james, absolutely. I just switched all my top level logging catches to Throwable.